# template associated with views style-plugin, and then customized for particular view: views does not find template

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have a style plugin, 'mystyle'. And I created a view, 'myview', with style set to 'mystyle'.

Here is the declaration of 'mystyle' in hook_view_plugins:

```
function mymodule_views_plugins() {
  $plugins = array(
    'module' => 'mymodule',
    'style' => array(
      'mystyle' => array(
        'title' => t('My Style'),
        'handler' => 'mymodule_views_plugin_mystyle',
        'theme' => 'mymodule_views_plugin_mystyle_template',
        'uses fields' => TRUE,
        'uses row plugin' => FALSE,
        'uses options' => TRUE,
        'uses grouping' => FALSE,
        'type' => 'normal',
        'even empty' => FALSE,
      ),
    )
  );
  return $plugins;
}
```

I have the following files in mymodule/views:

*(handler)*
mymodule_views_plugin_mystyle.inc

*(template associated with this style)*
mymodule-views-plugin-mystyle-template.tpl.php

*(template associated with this style, and customized for the view 'myview')*
mymodule-views-plugin-mystyle-template--myview.tpl.php

My problem:
Views is using the first, less specific, template (mymodule-views-plugin-mystyle-template.tpl.php) to display this view.

When I edit 'myview' and click on "theme information", I see both templates listed under "style output":

- mymodule-views-plugin-mystyle-template.tpl.php
- mymodule-views-plugin-mystyle-template--myview.tpl.php

The first, less specific, template is in bold. If I understand correctly, this means that views found the first template but did not find the second.

I have tried rescanning, but that does not help. I have also tried deleting the cache.

Should this work? What do I need to do to get views to find the more specific template?

Comment: I found the answer here:  http://drupal.org/node/1876760

Comment: could you please brief the answer here, that will help others who is looking for the same.

Comment: Here is the answer:  Drupal by default doesn't scan for more specific templates in modules directories, but views allows you to do it by adding 'template path'
to hook_views_api(), see http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_api/7

Comment: Great. you can add that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal by default doesn't scan for more specific templates in modules directories, but views allows you to do it by adding 'template path' to hook_views_api(), see: https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_api/7.x-3.x